# Perview Image in next img Tag Javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to preview Image in img tag that is after my input
My Html

```
          <input name="image" type="file"  id="uploadImage"  onchange="PreviewImage(this);" />
          <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
```

My JS

```
   function PreviewImage(input) {
        if (input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                     var imageObj=input.next();
consolde.log(imageObj);
                input.next('img').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

but i get error portfolio:766 Uncaught TypeError: input.next is not a function

Comment: next() is not a DOM method You are somehow using jQuery syntax. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yes I'm using jQuery

Comment: here i wnot want to use class or ids this is what i need but not working can  you help

Comment: so `$(input).next()`

Comment: @Kareimovich Are you still stuck with and need a jQuery solution ?

Comment: yes i'm using form repeater so i have no other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

JS

```
function previewFile() {
  const preview = document.querySelector('img');
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // convert image file to base64 string
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: in your case you should be able to replace input.next('img').attr('src', e.target.result); with $("#uploadPreview).attr('src', e.target.result) or with $(input).next().attr('src', e.target.result) if the img tag follows input tag immediately in HTML